# when evaluating populations, should I use Objects or Multiple Value Dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, dictionary

I wish to run a virtual experiment, where 100 "doves" and 100 "crows" populations are interacting. I wish to make multiple encounters between random birds, each encounter changes the 'Life' value of the birds. Then, I wish to view the populations (how many survived and in what condition...)

I have two optional ideas:

### option 1 - OOP

```
class Bird:

    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, creed, life):
        self.creed = creed
        self.life = life
```

and then, by using loop, creating 200 instances (100 where creed='Dove' and 100 creed='Crow')

### option 2 - Dictionary

```
Birds = {D1:("Dove", 10), C1:("Crow",10)}
```

...and then use loop to Birds.update fill in the ranks

Which option is better? (Memory consumption, CPU resources, ease of use when I update the 'life' values, ease of getting population statistics...)

Comment: Dict is the bare bones of a class. In your case, the class you have is naïve, so using a dict would be a. Understandable and readable b. Faster and less mem heavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would prefer 'ease of use' above Memory consumption and CPU resources in this case. Creating 400 instances is easy enough for any computer nowadays and going the OOP way is much easier fur future extensions to your model.

It all depends on your use-case, but I would prefer the OOP option in readability and ease of use.

Comment: I'll try to explain the use case with an example: I'm creating interactions between "birds" that changes their life variable. Once it reaches 0 - the bird is dead.
If I wish to calculate how many crows / doves are alive... Will a class method be the best idea, or should I calculate a dictionary?

Comment: full example with the calculations [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379089/counting-instances-of-a-class-based-on-attributes)

Comment: Looking at your project and the scope of it. I would definitely go for the OOP way. Your readability is better, and with this scope, you're not compromising on memory consumption or CPU resources. If you would ever want to upgrade to a model with more attributes for your birds, it would also be much easier this way. That's what I would do at least. Hope it helps you with your decision.